# How to add specific Style to Framework Elements contained on a User Control, with XAML?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I create a basic UserControl, called InputTag; it has two FrameworkElements a TextBlock and a Textbox.

Using the dependency properties I control the input for this control. The name of dependency properties are "Field" for the textblock, and "Value" for the Textbox.

The user control is compiled into a DLL (Class Library) and then loaded on a Windows Application.

Here is the XAML code for the UserControl:

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="FieldName" Text="Tag"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="FieldValue" Grid.Column="0" Text="0"/>
    </Grid>
```

And in the windows app MainWindow.xaml I insert the control like this

```
<t:InputTag  Field="Name" Value="" />
```

I want to add different styles to the Textblock and the TextBox using a Resource Dictionary, it should work like this

```
<t:InputTag  Field="Name" Value="" Style="{StaticResource InputTagStyle}"/>
```

For this example lets say we had two different font sizes. My Resource dictionary looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:t="clr-namespace:Terra.Controls;assembly=Terra">
    <Style x:Key="InputTagStyle" TargetType="{x:Type t:InputTag}">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource InputTagStyle}"/>
                        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource InputTextStyle}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="InputTagStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="InputTextStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to access a subkey of my control, and it seems that if I use ControlTemplate is like creating new content to my control.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to import the resources into your xaml as a pack URI format thus to import your styling keys in the  section like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Terra;component/Styles/ButtonStyles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I want is to access a control inside a UserControl via Resource dictionary. To be able to apply different properties to each of my Framework elements like the font size. 
Whithout using the style changing font size apply to both Textblock and Textbox, I don't how to access the subcontrols via xaml.

Comment: You have to expose the object as a property of the base control in the code behind. Add a property public TextBox TextB{get{return _TextBoxName}} and you can manipulate it that way

Comment: Okay  I add a new property and I can add costume style from the property, something like this.
<t:InputTag  Field="Name" Value="" FieldStyle="{StaticResource InputTagStyle}"/>
And it works, but doesn't answer how to access a sub key from a resource dictionary file in a <Style> tag.

Comment: You cannot that style key is private to the class that it's declared to, if you want to access it you need to create a resource dictionary and put the style in there.